# What is the best way to store constants in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, constants, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project (vuejs) and I'm wondering how to store constants in my project ? ( about 50 constants).

Thank you for your response.
kaboume

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a `constants.js` file:

```js
// constants.js
export const CONSTANT_1 = 'CONSTANT_1';
export const CONSTANT_2 = 'CONSTANT_2';
export const CONSTANT_3 = 'CONSTANT_3';
     
// And call it like this
import { CONSTANT_1 } from 'constants';
```

Comment: Niokobok bro / We togheter

Comment: How to use it inside the template tag?

Answer (score 16):

I think @Birante is just about right. Just because certain folders don't ship with the boilerplate doesn't mean you can't add them. However, I'd propose a structure like such,

```
|-- assets
|
|-- components
|   |-- Logo.vue
|   `-- index.js
|
|-- constants
|   |-- constants_002.js
|   |-- constants_001.js
|   `-- index.js
|
|-- layouts
|   |-- default.vue
|   `-- index.js
|
|-- middleware
|   `-- index.js
|
|-- pages
|   `-- index.vue
|
|-- plugins
|
|-- static
|
|-- store
|   `-- index.js
|
|-- test
|   `-- Logo.spec
|
`-- package.json
```

And then set up your constants in a modular fashion like you would any other part of your app.

constants/constants_001.js

```js
export const MY_FIRST_CONSTANT = 'is awesome'
```

constants/constants_002.js

```js
export const MY_SECOND_CONSTANT = 'is also awesome'
```

constants/index.js

```js
export * from './constants_001';
export * from './constants_002';
```

Then you can import your constants as per the convention used throughout your app.

```
import { MY_FIRST_CONSTANT, MY_SECOND_CONSTANT } from '@/constants/'
```

This is also a great convention for `utils` as well that you need to share across the application :)

Comment: do you happen to know if something is changed since this answer? I've pretty much copied and pasted your answer. And I get a ```"export 'MY_FIRST_CONSTANT' was not found in '@/constants/linkConstants'``` errors

Comment: Hey @Quickee. Sorry about that it looks like i dropped the `const` out of the export. The answer has been updated to read `export const MY_FIRST_CONSTANT = 'is awesome'`. Can you let me know if that works fine now?

Comment: yes that did fix it. but, only when i use them within the JS. im trying to use these consts inside the html as output or attribute values, i was able to achieve that by setting them to a data model  inside of created or mounted ```created () : {this.var = const}``` thanks a bunch

Comment: Nice one. Yeah if you want to do that you could bind them in your created method or just have them returned in your data object. You could also drop them into a computed property if need be.

Answer (score 6):

there is not best way it depends on the project and developer style and needs of project.

in some of my project I'm create the local folder and store some data like `breadcrumb` and `i18n` on it.

after that create file `constants.js` in `local` folder and just insert constant on it. like below

```js
const X="X";
const Y="Y";

export {
  X,
  Y
}
```

after that for simply use and didn't need to import them in every file I need them
create plugin for that like below

```js
import * as Constants from '@/locale/constants';

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    inject('constants', Constants)
}
```

after that I can use them in every file needed like below

```js
this.$constants.X
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it depends on the context. Most of the times, I find constants useful in the context of Vuex store for the mutations.

You can define the list of constants as follows:

```
// store/mutation-types.js
export const TOGGLE_MENU_STATE = 'TOGGLE_MENU_STATE';
```

And then use them in mutations files

```
import {
  TOGGLE_MENU_STATE,
} from '../store/mutation-types';

const mutations = {
  [TOGGLE_MENU_STATE](state) {
    state.isOpen = !state.isOpen;
  },
};

export default mutations;
```

Anyway, Nuxt is very deliberate about the folder structure and you can extend it further. For a non-store purposes, all things considered, I'd probably just create a `constants` folder and fill it with what you need.

```
// constants/app-constants.js -- example
export const HYDRATING_SUCCESS = 'HYDRATING_SUCCESS';
export const HYDRATING_FAILED = 'HYDRATING_FAILED';
export const LOADING = 'LOADING';
export const LOADED = 'LOADED';
export const SET_ERROR_STATE = 'SET_ERROR_STATE';
export const CLEAR_ERROR_STATE = 'CLEAR_ERROR_STATE';
...
```

And always import just the ones you need. The benefit also is that you can split the constants into several files by theme if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I use constant.js

```
   const api = "api";
   export default Object.freeze({
    api,
   });
```

Comment: In which file ? a plugin file ?

Comment: no in the plugin, create a folder in a root  then  made file in that which purpose of const

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805259/836701) I created a plugin with the dir structure:

```
|-- plugins
|   `-- config-constants
|   |   |-- config.ts
|   |   |-- index.ts
|   |   `-- messages.ts
|   `-- constants.js
```

And the code in `constants.ts`:

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import * as constants from './config-constants'
    
export default defineNuxtPlugin((_, inject) => {
  inject('const', constants)
})
```

The file `~/plugins/config-constants/index.ts` exports folder's files accordingly.

Besides that I added `type definitions` to use `$const` in component's `this` of Vue and also Vuex's and Nuxt's `context`:

```js
import * as constants from '~/plugins/config-constants'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $const: typeof constants
  }
}

declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  interface Context {
    $const: typeof constants
  }
}

declare module 'vuex' {
  interface ActionContext<S, R> {
    $const: typeof constants
  }
}
```